# Combining lists in python with unique elements but changing the third

Tags: python, merge, unique, mean

I have two different lists of experiments with three columns. I want to merge the lists in only one, but if they have the same first and second element, perform the mean between the thirds values, take that results and remove the other two.

Example:

List 1:

```
[[ 2, '+', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 6 ], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
```

List 2:

```
[[ 2, '-', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 2], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[ 2, '+', 4 ], [ 2, '-', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 4 ], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
```

I am trying iterating over the lists but I cannot avoid to append repetitive results.

Comment: So, the lists are always the same length, and you are always comparing elements at the same position?

Comment: @tobias_k: I don't think it matters that the lists are of the same length here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  dictionary to collect items based on their first two elements:

```
expressions = {}
for left, op, right in list1 + list2:
    expressions.setdefault((left, op), []).append(right)
```

then build a new list with the mean of the collected right-hand-side operands:

```
[[left, op] + [sum(rights) // len(rights)] for (left, op), rights in expressions.items()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [[ 2, '+', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 6 ], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
>>> list2 = [[ 2, '-', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 2], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
>>> expressions = {}
>>> for left, op, right in list1 + list2:
...     expressions.setdefault((left, op), []).append(right)
... 
>>> [[left, op] + [sum(rights) // len(rights)] for (left, op), rights in expressions.items()]
[[4, '-', 4], [8, '+', 2], [2, '-', 4], [2, '+', 4]]
```

Note that any ordering is lost as dictionaries don't track order; you'd have to switch to using `collections.OrderedDict()` if that matters.

Comment: This will also take the average if those "similar" elements are in different positions, or even in the same list. Not sure this is what OP wanted...

Comment: @tobias_k: I don't think this is about pairing up elements in the two lists; not sure where you got that notion from.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I got that notion from the fact that the lists in the example are the same length and the "similar" elements are always in the same position, and the result is in order. But seemingly this was just a somewhat misleading example, then.

Comment: @tobias_k: yes, it's not the greatest example input. The question body gives no indication that elements were to be paired up however.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want to compare *pairs* of elements, and if those pairs have the same first two elements, add the "mean" of that pair, otherwise add both elements to the list.

For iterating those pairs, you should use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function. Try this:

```
lst_A = [[ 2, '+', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 6], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
lst_B = [[ 2, '-', 4 ], [ 4, '-', 2], [ 8, '+', 2 ]]
res = []
for a, b in zip(lst_A, lst_B):
    if a[:2] == b[:2]:
        res.append([a[0], a[1], (a[2] + b[2])/2])
    else:
        res.extend([a, b])
```

Result is `[[2, '+', 4], [2, '-', 4], [4, '-', 4], [8, '+', 2]]`